# Given a unitary commutative ring $R$, what are the rings $R\langle x,y\rangle/(x^2-A,y^2-B,yx-a-bx-cy-dxy)$ called

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology, local-rings, noncommutative-rings

We are studying the rings

$$
  R \langle x, \, y \rangle\,\big/\left(x^2-A, \, y^2-B, \, yx-a-bx-cy-dxy \right)
$$

Do you know if they have a name?

Comment: Ok @YCor thanks

Comment: Of course, $A,B,a,b,c,d \in R$.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer your question on the terminology. Where did you encounter such rings and what is the motivation to study them? Just out of curiosity

Comment: We are studying this family of rings to find minimal rings with certain properties; in a few weeks we will have a preprint.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you manipulate this ring enough, you can get equations of the form $Cx + Dy + E = 0$, where $C, D, E$ are polynomials in $a, b, c, d, A, B$. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but an expansion of a comment.

The last equation says:

\begin{equation}
yx = a + bx + cy + dxy
\end{equation}
in the quotient ring.

Multiplying on the left by $y$ and substituting $B = yy$ where appropriate gives us:
\begin{equation}
Bx = yyx = ay + byx + cyy + dyxy = ay + ba + bbx + bcy + bdxy + cB + day + dbxy + dcyy + ddxyy = (ab + cB + dcB) + (bb + ddB)x + (a + bc + ad)y + (2bd)xy
\end{equation}

Alternatively,
\begin{equation}
(2bd)xy = -(ab + cB + dcB) - (bb + ddB - B)x - (a + bc + ad)y
\end{equation}

Multiplying on the right by $y$ and scaling by $2bd$:
\begin{equation}
(4bbdd)xB = -2bd(ab + cB + dcB)y - 2bd(bb + ddB - B)xy - 2bd(a + bc + ad)B
\end{equation}

Rearranging and substituting, we get:
\begin{equation}
4bbddBx + 2bd(ab + cB + dcB)y + 2bd(a + bc + ad)B = (bb + ddB - B)(ab + cB + dcB) + (bb + ddB - B)x + (a + bc + ad)y
\end{equation}

Rearranging further gives us
\begin{equation}
x(4bbddB - bb - ddB + B) + y(2abbd + 2bcdB + 2bcddB - a - bc - ad) + (2abd + 2bbcd + 2abdd - (bb + ddB - B)(ab + cB + dcB)) = 0
\end{equation}

As I haven't even used the equation $x^2 = A$, I'm pretty sure that this goes beyond what I said in the comment above, and presents a polynomial relation among $a, b, c, d, A, B$ in this quotient. I believe the relation to be:
\begin{equation}
a^4 - 2 a^2 A b^2 - 2 a^2 A B d^2 + 4 a^2 A B d - 2 a^2 A B - 2 a^2 B c^2 + 8 a A b B c d - 8 a A b B c + A^2 b^4 - 2 A^2 b^2 B d^2 + 4 A^2 b^2 B d - 2 A^2 b^2 B + A^2 B^2 d^4 - 4 A^2 B^2 d^3 + 6 A^2 B^2 d^2 - 4 A^2 B^2 d + A^2 B^2 - 2 A b^2 B c^2 - 2 A B^2 c^2 d^2 + 4 A B^2 c^2 d - 2 A B^2 c^2 + B^2 c^4 = 0
\end{equation}
If not, then it is a multiple of that; the above is the Groebner basis for the commutative version of the ring (h/t Wolfram Alpha).

This is not what I usually have seen when dealing with quotient rings like this; usually I expect some kind of PBW-like theorem. So I was curious as to whether this was intentional or not.